# Error MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-20, 20' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to fix this error?

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-20, 20' at line 1

The same script in my website is working properly but I uploaded to another server which is Windows server and received this error.

```
<?php

//connect to database
mysql_connect('xyz.ipowermysql.com','itomi','password.');
mysql_select_db('itomi');

$max_results = 20;
$from = (($page * $max_results) - $max_results);


if(empty($_POST)) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `itomi` WHERE `ntitle` LIKE '".$letter."%' ORDER BY `ntitle` ASC LIMIT $from, $max_results";
} 
$result = mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); //the main trick
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "<table class='hovertable' border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";
echo "<tr><th>Keyword</th><th>Title</th><th>Detail</th></tr>";

if ($rows > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo '<a href="detail.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '" class="style1">' .$row['ntitle'].' </a>';
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['ndetails'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['counter'];
        echo "</td></tr>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<tr><td colspan=\"5\">No results found!</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

// Figure out the total number of results in DB: 
$total_results = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as ntitle FROM itomi ORDER BY ntitle ASC"),0);

// Figure out the total number of pages. Always round up using ceil() 
$total_pages = ceil($total_results / $max_results);

// Build Page Number Hyperlinks 
echo "<p class=\"style1\">Pages: ";

// Build Previous Link 
if($page > 1){ 
    $prev = ($page - 1); 
    echo "<a href=\"".$_SERVER['php_SELF']."?page=$prev&letter=$letter\" class=\"style1\">Previous</a> "; 
}

for($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++){ 
    if(($page) == $i){ 
        echo "$i "; 
    } else { 
        echo " "; 
    }
}


// Build Next Link 
if($page < $total_pages){ 
    $next = ($page + 1); 
    echo "<a href=\"".$_SERVER['php_SELF']."?page=$next&letter=$letter\" class=\"style1\">Next</a>"; 
} 
echo "</p>";

mysql_close();
```

Comment: Seems like `$page` is empty or zero where it should be one or greater.

Answer (score 2):

Reading on the title which is part of the whole mysql syntax error message, the value you are passing on the `LIMIT` clause is less than the Minimum value of `0`.

```
LIMIT 0~, 1~
```

the problem is caused here:

```
$from = (($page * $max_results) - $max_results)
```

try this:

```
$partVal = (($page * $max_results) - $max_results);
$from = ($partVal <= 0 ? 0 : $partVal)
```

---

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: so how can i fix this

Comment: i update my code but now page is not opening and shwoing Server error

Comment: what is exactly the error?

Comment: $max_results = 20;
$partVal = (($page * $max_results) - $max_results);
$from = ($partVal <= 0 ? 0 : $partVal)
 i update this code

Comment: Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving  http://xyz.com/page.php It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.